# IE not align images properly

Tags: html

Simple HTML code:

```
<section class="">

<article class="">
  <h1>Staff Outing - June 29</h1>
  <p><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/homepage/pointPlay.jpg" width="150" height="113" align="right" >Join us this year on Friday, June 29, 2012, from 10:00am for the annual agency outing. Your <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>eventsCommittee">Events Committee</a> has everything in place for a fun and relaxing time for you and your family! Parking will be available, lunch will be provided and plenty of activities will be available for everyone to enjoy. For more information or for questions, please contact an <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>eventsCommittee">Events Committee</a> member!</p>
</article>
```

While is IE8 not aligning the image? It is currently aligned to the left. It doesn't really get any simpler than this, right?

Does this have something to do with the article/section tags?

Comment: Make sure you're closing your section tag and all other markup is formatted correctly.  Otherwise, IE might have a parsing issue.

Comment: Strange. Works for me http://jsbin.com/iropoc/edit#preview

Comment: You're also not closing your <img /> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of align='right' do style='float:right' if I understand what you want to do

Comment: Agreed. The align attribute is deprecated, but should work fine in IE8.

Comment: float: right; worked... but Josh is right, align should work in IE8. Whatever, too much to wrap my head around on a Friday. Thanks for the tip!